# Semantic UI - links in dropdown nested menu won't work

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I would like to implement links in nested submenus but it doesn't seem willing to work.

```
<div class="ui menu">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <span class="text">Menu</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <span class="text">Sub Menu</span>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="header">Links</div>
            <div class="item"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The links in the submenu will not work (though links in the menu will).

Is this a bug or a "normal" feature. Has anyone find a way around this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the div in the leaf menu item - try this under the links sub menu

```
<a class="item" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```